# Replace List Title with List Title + Site Title

Tags: list, list-view, title

I'm currently using the following script on one of our sites to replace the List Title with the List Title + View Title;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Replace default page title with document.title, which is based on view name
document.getElementById("DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").innerHTML = document.title;  
</script>
```

I want to change this so that instead of using the View Name, it uses the Site Name, but I'm not entirely sure how this script works.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `_spPageContextInfo`, there's and attribute called "`webTitle`" wich returns the name of the site collection:

```
document.getElementById("DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").innerHTML = document.getElementById("DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").innerHTML + " - " + _spPageContextInfo.webTitle;
```

Comment: @JordanSmith Please don't forget to Mark the answer as accepted!